# How to change this array to work with google maps api

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

This is the array I have that has been json encoded and I am trying to make it work with google maps api:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Something
            [lat] => -25.364
            [long] => 131.044
            [id] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Hello world!
            [lat] => 53.4315768
            [long] => -2.9634503
            [id] => 1
        )

)
```

Built with this: (a lot of this is wordpress specific)

```
function wp_cat_map_wp_query() {

$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post',

    'orderby' => 'title',

    'order' => 'desc',

    'meta_query' => array (

        array (

        'key' => '_wp_cat_map_long',

        'value' => '',

        'compare' => '!='

        ),

        array (

        'key' => '_wp_cat_map_lat',

        'value' => '',

        'compare' => '!='

        )        

    ),

);

$mapdata = get_posts($args); 

if( is_array($mapdata) ) {  

    foreach($mapdata as $map) { 


        // Cook up the listing data 

        $permalink  = get_permalink($map->ID);

        $long       = get_post_meta($map->ID,'_wp_cat_map_long',true);  

        $lat        = get_post_meta($map->ID,'_wp_cat_map_lat',true);                   

        $image      = get_the_post_thumbnail( $map->ID ); 



        // Build json array

        $json[] = array(    

            "title" => strip_tags(str_replace("'","",substr($map->post_title,0,20))),   

            "lat"   => $lat,

            "long"  => $long,

            "id"    => $map->ID

        );  
    }
} 

//echo '<pre>';print_r($json);echo '</pre>';

// Return json output

if(empty($json)){ return ""; }else{ return json_encode($json);  }


}
```

How would I convert it into an array like the one below to work with google maps api?

```
var beaches = [
   ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
   ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
   ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
   ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
   ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change your key names, but I think this will work:

```
var beaches = <?= json_encode($php_array);?>;
```

Comment: Oh yea sorry I was echoing it in a pre before the encode

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is an list of lists in javascript. You would have to convert the original data in php to the equivalent and then return it as json. I would opt for a function to do that.

```
<?php
function convertMapDataInfo($mapData) {
    // defining the outer list
    $newArray = array();
    if(is_array($mapData) && count($mapData)>0) {
        // iterate each list
        foreach($mapData as $key => $value) {
            // convert it to the structure equivalent to the
            // javascript 
            $currentInfo = array(
                                 $value['title'],
                                 $value['lat'],
                                 $value['long'],
                                 $value['id']
                           );
            // then appending the inside list to the outer list
            $newArray[] = $currentInfo;
        }
    }
    // return the outer list with all the lists inside as a json. 
    // Which is what google api expects
    return json_encode($newArray);
}
```

And then call it and pass it to the javascript variable:

```
<?php $googleMapData = convertMapDataInfo($mapdata);  ?>

<script>
var beaches = <?= $googleMapData; ?>
</script>
```